# How do I keep mysql tables from wrapping in Windows cmd using DESCRIBE?

Tags: mysql, cmd

So given:

```
CREATE TABLE stuff (
    really_long_title int(10) NO NULL auto_increment,
    really_long_title_number_1 varchar(10) NO NULL auto_increment,
    PRIMARY KEY (blah)
);
DESCRIBE table;
```

I would like to be shown my table with two rows (blah and blah1) and attributes for each.  Instead I'm shown the two rows of my table but in the "extra" field where "auto_increment" would be show it is cut off about half way through and the words and table outline wrap around to the next line. I can't expand cmd in win7 large enough so that cmd won't wrap my databases around on top of themselves. There must be a better way to view my table.
thanks.

Comment: Is there some way you could export your results to a text file, similar to the " > c:\myfile.txt" shortcut for most simple console applications (e.g. `ping google.com > c:\test.txt`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click the upper left hand corner icon, you can change the window and buffer width:

`Context Menu > Properties > Layout`

Up the screen buffer width and the window width to 160 or whatever fits on your screen. The other option would be to try what I put in my comment on your question, somehow export the results to a text file and view it in a text editor.

UPDATE:

I guess you can also start the `mysql` app with a switch to output everything to a log file. Something like:

`mysql --tee logfile.txt`

Comment: I had looked at both of these and I suppose either one is a usable short term solution. I guess ideally I was hoping for some way to resize the physical tables in mysql server. Does this exist?